# how to run multiple observables in sequence

Tags: rxjs

I have an array of observables `a$, b$, c$, d$`. I want them them to run in sequence. E.g. if `a$` finishes, then `b$`. If `b$` finishes then `$c` ...

I know `forkJoin([a$, b$, c$, d$])` except that it will do this in parallel. Is there a corresponding operator? Or can I tell `forkJoin` to run in sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) to run them in sequence:

```
concat(a$, b$, c$).subscribe(console.log);
```

If you also want to skip any intermediate emissions from the source observables on the resulting observer, you can use something like

```
concat(...[a$, b$, c$].map(source$ => source$.pipe(last())));
```

… or if you want to only collect the last emission of each source observable into a single emission like `forkJoin`, you attach `toArray` to it:

```
concat(...[a$, b$, c$].map(source$ => source$.pipe(last()))).pipe(
  toArray(),
);
```

Of course you could extract this into your own operator now if you want:

```
const concatLast = <T>(...sources: Observable<T>) => concat(
  ...sources.map(source$ => source$.pipe(last()))
).pipe(
  toArray(),
);
```

There are still fine differences to `forkJoin` in how it behaves when one of the source observables completes without emitting.

---

On the rxjs website there's a useful tool called the [operator decision tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree) which helps you figure out the appropriate operator, for example in this case

- I have some Observables to combine together as one Observable, and
- I want to subscribe to each in order

Comment: is there a way to behave concat like forkJoin? e.g. that it waits until all abservables have completed

Comment: @matthias I also see that you don't tend to accept answers on your questions lately. It would be nice feedback to the people answering as well as other readers coming along if you made use of up-/downvotes and accepting answers to questions.